# Paypal IPN always INVALID on ie11

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, internet-explorer-11

Paypal IPN  always INVALID, on ie11, in the destination page after the transation. but the transaction happens and I get the e-mails from paypal, etc.

On Chrone there in no problema , and I get VERIFIED

Anybody has experienced this?

Comment: Do you mean PDT and not IPN? IPN is a direct call sent from Paypal to you.

Comment: Yes, PDT.
I'm "echoing" my _POST vars and I am not getting callback vars from paypal in internet explorer. But the trasaction did occur.
In google chrome everything works fine.

Comment: I'm guessing it is a charset issue because if I use "<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="iso-8859-1">" in the form, it stops working on Chrome too (no _POST vars passed from paypal )
My pages are set iso-8859-1. I'm Portuguese. In the paypal account it is also set for iso-8859-1.

Comment: I'm not sure for PDT, but in the API all values must be formatted with UTF8. So it wouldn't surprise me another charset would be your problem

Comment: I have been googleing for a while, and everyting seems by the book.
Can't really find/imagine a reason for working in google and firefox and not working on ie ... 
Website is ready to be public, but at the last test I found out this "bug".

Comment: verify the values coming from PayPal using the F12 tools. You can see all the requests in the networking tab. It will let you examine the response content, headers etc. Tell us what you see.